# iOS app crashing randomly due to to Google analytics code

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Application is crashing randomly due to Google Analytics code. Used Google Analytics SDK for iOS v3.

Following is the crash log -

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b27da84 0x3b27d000 + 2692
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b27d87c 0x3b27d000 + 2172
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309b055c 0x30911000 + 652636
3   CoreFoundation                  0x309aec7c 0x30911000 + 646268
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3091953c 0x30911000 + 34108
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3091931e 0x30911000 + 33566
6   Foundation                      0x31307822 0x312fc000 + 47138
7   Foundation                      0x31358664 0x312fc000 + 378468
8   **MyApp                         0x004d1f24 +[GAI threadMain:] + 60**
9   Foundation                      0x313c9dc2 0x312fc000 + 843202
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b2f6c5a 0x3b2f4000 + 11354
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b2f6bca 0x3b2f4000 + 11210
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b2f4ccc 0x3b2f4000 + 3276
```